# css only solution for scaling + overflow

Tags: css, overflow, transform, scale

I want to show a html of undefined width and height at a scale of 0.5 in a scrollable pane.

So I style the container this way

```
.container {
 position:absolute;
 top:40px;
 left:40px;
 bottom:40px;
 right:40px; 
 overflow:scroll;
}
```

and the content

```
.content {
 transform:scale(0.5);
 transform-origin: top left;
}
```

The problem is that the scale factor only change the visual aspect of the block, it didn't affect its inner container.
If the content was 1000 x 2000, at 0.5 scale the visible area is 500 x 1000 but its "implicit" container is still 1000 x 2000.

So if i put it in a parent container with overflow:scroll then the scroll bar start to show empty content as soon as you pass 50%

What is the solution ? Preferably in css. Or javascript if this is not possible in pure css.

```css
.content {
 transform:scale(0.5);
 transform-origin: top left;
}

.container {
 position:absolute;
 top:40px;
 left:40px;
 bottom:40px;
 right:40px; 
 overflow:scroll;
}

/* css behind does not matter */
span
{
 display:block;
 width:400px;
 height:400px;
 background-color:red;
 border:1px solid green;
}
span:nth-child(2n)
{
 height:300px;
 background-color:yellow;
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>

<div class="container">
 <div class="content">

    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span> 
    ...when zoomed there are empty space here under ...
    
 </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: but the height of the container is not defined by the content, it's defined by top/bottom

Comment: The problem is not the height of the container (you could use a fixed height if you'd prefer). The problem is "height" of the scrollbars. Their length are 2x times 
what is necessary because they are based on height of child BEFORE the scaling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just set `height:0` to `.content`:

```css
.content {
 transform:scale(0.5);
 transform-origin: top left;
 height: 0;
}

.container {
 position:absolute;
 top:40px;
 left:40px;
 bottom:40px;
 right:40px; 
 overflow:scroll;
}

/* css behind does not matter */
span
{
 display:block;
 width:400px;
 height:400px;
 background-color:pink;
 border:1px solid green;
}
span:nth-child(2n)
{
 height:300px;
 background-color:gold;
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>

<div class="container">
 <div class="content">

    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span> 
    ...when zoomed there are empty space here under ...
    
 </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: indeed it looks like it works. Even if I don't understand why. What does the 100% in contant mean ? 100% of container ? (it looks like it's not) so this is 100% of necessary space to display child ? Looks strange but this is exactly what it was looking. IRL the span are iframe so I'll look if it's still working with iframe

Comment: @frenchone, I've updated my answer so it does not confuse you with `100%`. Overflow would reserve the overflowing height only.

Comment: It only adds more confusion ;)